# Are plasmids found in eukaryotes?

Tags: cell-biology, microbiology, prokaryotes, eukaryotes

There are some who says plasmids are found in some eukaryotes but is it like scientifically proven?

Comment: Welcome to SE.biology. Please take a look around the [help center](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question. In particular, it's expected you show evidence of prior research on your question, and also include links to information you cite, rather than just 'there are some who say...'. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

These resources may help.

This [book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540157984), “Plasmids of Eukaryotes”, explains that...

“The possession of plasmids was for a long time recognized only in the bacteria. It is now evident that plasmids, or replicative forms of DNA structurally and experimentally comparable to bacterial plasmids, exist in eukaryotic organisms as well. Such plasmids are in fact common among fungi and higher plants.”

Also, this [website](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/biochemistry-genetics-and-molecular-biology/plasmid) (ScienceDirect) explains that...

“Most plasmids inhabit bacteria, and indeed around 50% of bacteria found in the wild contain one or more plasmids. Plasmids are also found in higher organisms such as yeast and fungi. The 2 micron circle of yeast (discussed later) is a well-known example that has been modified for use as a cloning vector.“